# #1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, database

I need help in something for my work.

I have this code:

```
    ALTER TABLE `utentes_old`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `utentes_old_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`idConcelho`) REFERENCES `concelhos` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `utentes_old_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`idFreguesia`) REFERENCES `freguesias` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `utentes_old_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`idEstadoCivil`) REFERENCES `estadoscivis` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `utentes_old_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`idHabilitacoes`) REFERENCES `habilitacoes` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `utentes_old_ibfk_5` FOREIGN KEY (`idGrupoEtario`) REFERENCES `gruposetarios` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `utentes_old_ibfk_6` FOREIGN KEY (`idGenero`) REFERENCES `generos` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `utentes_old_ibfk_7` FOREIGN KEY (`idSituacaoRegularizada`) REFERENCES `situacaonopaisregularizada` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `utentes_old_ibfk_8` FOREIGN KEY (`idInscritoCE`) REFERENCES `inscritocentrodeemprego` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `utentes_old_ibfk_9` FOREIGN KEY (`idSituacaoDeEmprego`) REFERENCES `situacaodeemprego` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `utentes_old_ibfk_10` FOREIGN KEY (`idTempoDesemprego`) REFERENCES `tempodesemprego` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `utentes_old_ibfk_11` FOREIGN KEY (`idFrontOfficeSinalizador`) REFERENCES `instituicoes` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `utentes_old_ibfk_12` FOREIGN KEY (`idTecnico`) REFERENCES `tecnicos` (`id`);
```

But when I import the script to phpmyadmin they give me this error:

```
    SQL query:

--
-- Limitadores para a tabela `utentes_old`
--
ALTER TABLE `utentes_old`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `utentes_old_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`idConcelho`) REFERENCES `concelhos` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `utentes_old_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`idFreguesia`) REFERENCES `freguesias` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `utentes_old_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`idEstadoCivil`) REFERENCES `estadoscivis` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `utentes_old_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`idHabilitacoes`) REFERENCES `habilitacoes` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `utentes_old_ibfk_5` FOREIGN KEY (`idGrupoEtario`) REFERENCES `gruposetarios` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `utentes_old_ibfk_6` FOREIGN KEY (`idGenero`) REFERENCES `generos` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `utentes_old_ibfk_7` FOREIGN KEY (`idSituacaoRegularizada`) REFERENCES `situacaonopaisregularizada` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `utentes_old_ibfk_8` FOREIGN KEY (`idInscritoCE`) REFERENCES `inscritocentrodeemprego` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `utentes_old_ibfk_9` FOREIGN KEY (`idSituacaoDeEmprego`) REFERENCES `situac[...]
MySQL said: Documentation

#1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

Please can someone help me?

Comment: Try adding them one at a time and see which one is generating the error.

Answer (score 0):

Removes the single quotes which you have given for table name , constraint name,reference name . It is a syntax error .

Comment: Those aren't single quotes but backticks, they should work.

Answer (score 0):

The two most common errors are that foreign key and primary key/index don not  have the exact same data type, or the primary key is not defined correctly.

Also you don't need all those backticks / single quotes. You only need them when your names and identifiers  contain whitespace, or special characters, which is not the case in your statements.

Answer (score 0):

Without having all of your database schema it is really hard to tell which one is causing the problem, but I would check various things:

- Ensure that a constraint with a given name doesn't already exist. You can't have duplicate constraints.
- Ensure the data type of the column and the one it references are the same.
- Since you're using foreign key, verify that the "id" column in each of the adjacent tables are primary keys. You cannot create a foreign key reference to a column that is not the primary key.

There may be others, and I will edit to add as I think of them, but these are three most common situations that I see myself.